# Bucle infinito cuando introduzco un caracter en vez de un entero en C++

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema con una agenda telefonica que estoy creando. A la hora de que me pida el numero, si introduzco un caracter, el bucle se repite infinitamente sin darme la posibilidad de reintroducir el número haga lo que haga. Tengo esos dos bloques de codigo, el codigo que me permite añadir un contacto y el que comprueba cuantos dígitos tiene que tener el número. No logro comprender el por qué se queda con un bucle infinito y he probado con comprobaciones de si el std::cin ha fallado y demás. ¿Alguna solución viable?

```
void AgendaTelefonica::addContacto()
{
Contacto auxiliar;
string nombreAux;
int numAux;

cout<<"Ahora va a agregar un contacto. Introduzca su nombre: ";
cin>>nombreAux;

cout<<"\nIntroduzca su numero de telefono: ";
cin>>numAux;

while((int)contarDigitos(numAux)!=9 || !std::cin)
{
    cin.ignore();
    cin.clear();
    cout<<"Por favor,introduzca un numero de 9 digitos: ";
    cin>>numAux;
}

auxiliar.nombre = nombreAux;
auxiliar.numeroTfn = numAux;

int j = 1;

for(int i=0;i<j;i++)
{
    if(contactos[i].nombre == "")
    {
        auxiliar.posicion = i;
    }
    else{j++;}
}

cout<<"\nLa posicion del contacto es "<<auxiliar.posicion<<endl;

contactos[auxiliar.posicion] = auxiliar;

numContactos++;
}



int AgendaTelefonica::contarDigitos(int numero)
{
int n = numero;
int count = 0;

while (n != 0)
{
    n /= 10;
    count++;
}

return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tengo la respuesta a tu pregunta

El problema se debe a que cuando introduces el carácter en cin al esperar un número, ese carácter lo ignora, encuentra un salto de línea y para, como el bucle se repite al no introducir el número, se vuelve a imprimir el cout y vuelve a lanzarse el cin, como el salto de línea sigue existiendo, se creará un bucle infinito.
cin tiene un metodo ,fail que detecta bueno si la entrada de datos es erronea

```
void clear_cin() {
 std::cin.clear(); // limpiamos el estado de cin para que quede como good()
 std::cin.ignore(80, '\n'); // ignoramos todos los carácteres (máximo 80) hasta fin de línea.
}

if (std::cin.fail()) { // Si no nos ha introducido un número, cin queda en el estado "fail"
    clear_cin(); // limpiamos cin para que vuelva a un estado correcto
    std::cout << "debe ser un número" << std::endl;
}
```

Cualquier duda me dices

Comment: Me has ayudado muchisimo, muchas gracias. Ahora la unica duda que a la hora de modificar un contacto, realizo el mismo procedimiento, pido el nombre, si lo encuentra me pide darle otro nombre y otro número, pero no se el por qué, cuando introduzco el nuevo número en la variable auxiliar, entra dentro del bucle y me pregunta otra vez por otro numero de 9 digitos cuando el que he introducido es de 9.

EDIT: Vale nada, era por un ";" al final del while, que supongo que eso lo convertirá en un do...while. Mil perdones y muchas gracias.

Comment: @AbsydeAuberon si esta respuesta soluciona el problema planteado en la pregunta, por favor, márcala como solución. Adicionalmente, si crees que la respuesta es lo suficientemente interesante plantéate votarla positivamente

Comment: Gracias @eferion y me alegra haber ayudado

Comment: Me seria de gran ayuda que si la respuesta es correcta q me la marcaras como solución quiero subir mi reputación. Gracias y saludos

Comment: @AbsydeAuberon por favor marca la respuesta como aceptada es en la palomita...